# Do the position and velocity vectors live in the same space?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-spaces

This is a question I've been thinking about for a while. Position vectors are supposed be represented by an arrow from the origin that traces out a path, while one does not need to think of the velocity vector as having any sort of starting point because as long as the length and direction and the same, they represent the same velocity. From a pure math perspective, a vector space is just an object with a dozen or so properties with closure being one of them. But it makes no sense to add a position and a velocity vector right? So that means they do not belong to the same vector space. But at the same time, it is possible to take the dot or cross products of a position and velocity vector. So how do you explain that?

Also when we learn multivariable calculus, why do we need the position vector to originate from the origin? $\Bbb R^3$ or $\Bbb R^2$ satisfies all the properties of a vector space without needing to conjure up any sort arrow.

Comment: the velocity vector of a curve lives in the tangential space of the base space. If the base space is $\Bbb R^n$ then we knows that $T\Bbb R^n\cong\Bbb R^n$, however this last $\Bbb R^n$ is a different space from the base. This is standard theory in differential geometry. And yes, you cannot add position and velocity vectors. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space)

Comment: Thanks! I assumed differential geometry would cover most of this. I haven't learned any of this yet, but can you explain what the theory is with taking dot products of the velocity and acceleration vector? In many physical situations their dot product is 0 because they are orthogonal, but since they are also in different vector space, why are we allowed to take dot products of things not in the same space?

Comment: I never see taking cross or dot product of position vector and tangent vector. It would be very strange as the position vector is generally not important and can be anything as you can take any coordinates to represent it, so something that depend on the position is rare. Anyway I dont know about physics. However its true that if you take to tangent vector to a surface then it cross product gives a normal vector to this surface.

Comment: On a general smooth manifold, velocity lives in the tangent bundle, and acceleration, as a derivative of velocity, lives in the tangent bundle of the tangent bundle. In situations like this, one needs an additional, non-canonical piece of information, a *connection*, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(differential_geometry)). Via so-called "horizontal lifts" you can then transport vectors between different bundles. On Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$, you don't see this, because there's a canonical connection. There's a lot to this, but let's not flood the comment section!

Comment: @Masacroso As an example where the cross product of position and velocity shows up, the usual three-dimensional formula for the angular momentum is $m \cdot \vec{r} \times \vec{v}$. So this does happen, and it takes a bit of thinking why that makes sense in general coordinates...

Comment: There is general a concept of **phase space** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) which is a space that represents all possible states of a system. In classical mechanics, under Newton's laws, the evolution of a system is dictated by the position and momentum (velocity times mass) of its elements and the forces acting upon it and these data make up the phase space. The easiest situation is that of a single particle moving freely in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and thus the phase space is $\mathbb{R}^6$.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to distinguish between the space of points, which is also known as affine space (let's denote this by $A$), and the space of vectors $V$. The space of points looks a lot like a vector space except there is no point called the origin, so an element in affine space is depicted as just a dot and not an arrow. A vector $v \in V$ is an arrow you can slide around in $A$. The assumption is that given any two points $p, q \in A$, there is a unique vector that starts at $p$ and ends at $q$.

You can indeed add a vector $v$ to a point $p$ by positioning the start of the vector at $p$ and defining $p+v$ to be the point at the end of the vector. You can also subtract two points $p$ and $q$ by defining $q-p$ to be the vector that goes from $p$ to $q$. But it makes no sense to add two points together.

However, if you choose a point $p_0$ in affine space, there is a unique vector from $p_0$ to each point $p$. This is the position vector of a point $p$ relative to $p_0$. So there is a natural isomorphism $I_{p_0}: A \rightarrow V$, where $I(p) = p-p_0$, identifying each point with a vector. The definition of the position vector depends on which point $p_0$ you choose to be effectively the origin of space.

So points and vectors live in different spaces, but the position vector does live in the same vector space as the vector itself.